# Create a controller and a empty theme page

Tags: page-controller

On Drupal 8, I'm looking for a way for creating an empty page (a page without any theme) that contains JavaScript code.
I created a controller via Drupal Console, and I searched for an example on the web, but I found only very simple examples.

Is it possible to create an empty page accessible via a controller and add JavaScript code to this page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controllers must return a response (you will get an error if you don't). Your options are to return a render array, an [HtmlResponse](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21HtmlResponse.php/class/HtmlResponse/8.3.x), a [JsonResponse](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/8.3.x/search/JsonResponse), or an [AjaxResponse](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Ajax%21AjaxResponse.php/class/AjaxResponse/8.3.x).

Edit: Or as Kevin posted below, a [Response](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21Response.php/class/Response/8.3.x).

By the sounds of it, you are wanting to return JSON, so JsonResponse is likely what you are looking for.

Comment: If you also use the Symfony Response class, I believe you will get what the OP is asking. It will by pass all the Drupal related events and serve it. Although unless you're an expert, I don't see where that is too useful.

Comment: @Kevin, I agree, a symfony response is probably not useful here, because it bypasses drupal completely and the OP wants to attach javascript libraries in a drupal way. In this case it's better to use a custom page.html.twig and remove anything to get an empty page.

Comment: For the question after the edit (javascript in a drupal way removed) you can simply put the javascript in the symfony response in a <script> tag.